# Why can't I configure a device on Firebase Test Lab to use API Level 23?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I was trying to reproduce an issue in my Android app specific to a Galaxy S6 running Android 6.0.1, but none of the devices listed will support API Level 23. I tried all of the devices with API Level 23 and for each one it says "1 device/API level combination is unsupported and will be marked as skipped in the test matrix." I looked for anything that said that API Level 23 will be supported soon but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, we do not have support for API level 23 for the Galaxy S6.  That may change in the future as we are always looking to expand our device and API level support, but we aren't able to give a date on that.  We do currently support API level 23 for a virtual Nexus 6 device.

If you want to stay in the loop on Test Lab and get more direct support from the staff, please considering [joining the discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-test-lab-external).